# Links to security companies with license to sponsor in the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, visa

I am presently scouting for a security and safety job in the UK. Is it possible to get a job offer in the UK from a security outfit that is licensed to sponsor before approaching the embassy for visa application?

Answer (score 0):

this is the official UK government list of all companies that can sponsor work visas. Unless you have specialist skills you are unlikely to get a visa for security work since all companies must try to find a UK or EU worker first. https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/register-of-licensed-sponsors-workers